# How to get an alert when a user deletes a sharepoint site.

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I know we can setup alerts for things like libraries and lists WITHIN site to tell us that something has been deleted and the name of the user.

However, I need a way to get an alert for when somebody deletes an entire site and the user's name.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Sameer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an event receiver for the SiteDeleted event. You can find a short guide on how to create event receivers like this at the link below, though obviously you would want to modify the code to send an alert email or something.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2012/09/07/how-to-prevent-site-deletion-with-a-custom-event-receiver/